# What test frameworks can I use against a SPA based mobile application?

Tags: android, ios

A client has native single page applications, apparently written in Clojure running on ios and android.

I'm used to writing user-acceptance testing with Selenium and the ruby bindings present in capybara through the rspec framework.

What automated ui testing tools can I use against these native apps ?